# Printing a different value other than those stated in the <input>

Tags: javascript, php, forms, get

I am attempting to produce a combined 'Order Form' and 'Order Calculator' in one php form.

The 'calculator' aspects work perfectly for my needs at this point.

The form aspects work well too, except... I need to adjust a few parts of the php output.

I have included the code below, divided by the HTML page and the PHP page.

I have included 'Notes' in the PHP page to describe what I am attempting to achieve.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<title>Ice Cream Order Form</title>

<style> 

.plus { display: none; } 

</style>

</head>

<body>

<form action="icecream_formHandler.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<h1>Customer Ice Cream Order Form and Order Calculator</h1>

<p>In this example, the customer would enter their info., make their selections, get an order 
total and then place their order through the email form.</p><br>

<input type="text" id="customerName" name="customerName" placeholder=" Enter Your Name"><br> 
<br>

<input type="email" id="customerEmail" name="customerEmail" placeholder=" Enter Your Email"> 
<br><br>

<input type="tel" id="customerPhone" name="customerPhone" placeholder=" Enter Your Phone 
Number"><br><br>

<select id="flavor" name="flavor">

<option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Select Your Flavor</option> 
<option value="Vanilla">Vanilla</option> 
<option value="Chocolate">Chocolate</option>
<option value="Strawberry">Mixed</option>

</select><br><br>

<select id="scoops" name="scoops" onchange="calcuMath()">

<option value='0' selected="true" disabled="disabled">How Many Scoops?</option> 
<option value="3">One Scoop - $3.00</option> 
<option value="5">Two Scoops - $5.00</option>
<option value="7">Three Scoops - $7.00</option>

</select><br><br>

<p>Toppings: (Optional)</p>

<select id="plus" class="plus"><option value="add" id="add">+</option></select>

<input type="hidden" id="nuts" name="nuts" value="0"><input type="checkbox" 
onchange="this.previousSibling.value=3-this.previousSibling.value; calcuMath();">&nbspNuts 
$3.00<br><br>

<select id="plus" class="plus"><option value="add" id="add">+</option></select>

<input type="hidden" id="sprinkles" name="sprinkles" value="0"><input type="checkbox" 
onchange="this.previousSibling.value=3-this.previousSibling.value; 
calcuMath();">&nbspSprinkles $3.00<br><br>

<select id="plus" class="plus"><option value="add" id="add">+</option></select>

<input type="hidden" id="syrup" name="syrup" value="0"><input type="checkbox" 
onchange="this.previousSibling.value=4-this.previousSibling.value; calcuMath();">&nbspSyrup 
$4.00<br><br><br>

<select id="plus" class="plus"><option value="add" id="add">+</option></select>

<select id="dish" name="dish" onchange="calcuMath()">

<option value='0' selected="true" disabled="disabled">Cup or Cone</option> 
<option value="3">Cup - $3.00</option>
<option value="4">Cone - $4.00</option> 

</select><br><br><br>

TOTAL: $<a id="result"></a><br><br>

<script>

function calcuMath() {
var z;
var a = document.getElementById("scoops").value;
var b = document.getElementById("nuts").value;
var c = document.getElementById("sprinkles").value;
var d = document.getElementById("syrup").value;
var e = document.getElementById("dish").value;
var sel = document.getElementById("plus");
var selection = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
var more = document.getElementById("add");
if (selection == "add") 
{ z = parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b) + parseFloat(c) + parseFloat(d) + parseFloat(e); }

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "" + z + ""; }   
        
</script>

<input type="submit" id="submitButton" name="submitButton" value="Place Order">

</form>

</body>

</html>
```

PHP

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['customerName'];
$email = $_POST['customerEmail'];
$phone = $_POST['customerPhone'];
$flavor = $_POST['flavor'];
$scoops = $_POST['scoops'];
$nuts = $_POST['nuts'];
$sprinkles = $_POST['sprinkles'];
$syrup = $_POST['syrup'];
$dish = $_POST['dish'];
$total = $_POST['results'];


$composition =

"\r\nCUSTOMER ICE CREAM ORDER" .

"\r\n\nName: ". $name .
"\r\nEmail Address: " . $email .
"\r\nPhone: " . $phone .
"\r\nNumber of Scoops: ". $scoops . 
"\r\nNuts: " . $nuts .
"\r\nSprinkles: " . $sprinkles .
"\r\nSyrup: " . $syrup .
"\r\nDish: " . $dish .
"\r\nTotal: $" . $total ;

//  In the composition output above... Instead of their respective values of '3','3' or '4'... 
I would like 'Nuts:', 'Sprinkles:', and 'Syrup' to be followed by either: 'Yes' (if selected) 
or 'No'(if not selected). 


// Also, in the $composition output, I would like $total to produce the same output (number) 
as 'result' does in the script on the html page.


//For this example, please disregard any non-applicable php beyond this point //

$subject ="Customer Ice Cream Order";

$fromname ="$name";
$fromemail = "$email";

$mailto = 'recieving@email.com';


$content = file_get_contents($fileName);
$content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
$separator = md5(time());
$eol = "\r\n";
$headers = "From: ".$fromname." <".$fromemail.">" . $eol;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . $eol;
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"" . $separator . "\"" . $eol;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit" . $eol;
$headers .= "This is a MIME encoded message." . $eol;
$body = "--" . $separator . $eol;
$body .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"" . $eol;
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit" . $eol;
$body .= $composition . $eol;
$body .= "--" . $separator . $eol;
$body .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"" . $filenameee . "\"" . $eol;
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" . $eol;
$body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment" . $eol;
$body .= $content . $eol;
$body .= "--" . $separator . "--";

@mail($mailto, $subject, $body, $headers);


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, you can try `$nuts = isset($_POST['nuts']) ? 'Yes' : 'No';`. Because if checkbox is not selected, the key and value will not be sent to your php script.

For your second question, you got two ways to do it:

1. Do it again in php, like `$total = floatval($_POST['scoops'] ?? 0) + floatval($_POST['nuts']) ?? 0 + ...`
2. Add a `<input type='hidden' name='total' id='total'>` to your form, and add `onsubmit="your_function"` to your form,it can do something before your form been posted, and you can get the result and put the value to the `<input>` with id `total`, and after the form submitted you can get `$_POST['total']` in your php.

Comment: bubbak... Thank you for your help. For the first question, your suggestion of $nuts = isset($_POST['nuts']) ? 'Yes' : 'No'; worked! || For the second question... the hidden input with an id of 'total' solution did not work. || The PHP $total = floatval($_POST['scoops'] ?? 0) + floatval($_POST['nuts']) ?? 0 + ... solution worked. || However, it only tabulated the <select> field values and disregarded the checkbox values. I am assuming that's because we converted them to 'Yes' and 'No', so values were no longer available when $total called for their floatval? Any suggestions for a work-around ?

Comment: `$nuts = isset($_POST['nuts']) ? 'Yes' : 'No';` wont change the value of `$_POST['nuts']`, it only put Yes or No to `$nuts`, so you should not use `floatval($nuts)` to get total, you should use `floatval($_POST['nuts'] ?? 0)`

Comment: And in your code `<input type="hidden" id="nuts" name="nuts" value="0">` means $_POST['nuts'] will always be 0, if you want to make it as checkbox you should use `<input type="checkbox" id="nuts" name="nuts" value="put the real value you want when it is checked here">`